# Get full operating system name in WIX

Tags: wix

I'm trying to determine if the system is windows server 2008 r2. Windows 7 comes with the same VersionNT number so I've tried to use the MSINTProductType but this message is still being thrown on a windows 7 system.

My WIX code at the moment is:

```
<Condition Message="For windows 2008 R2 system application server role service is required>
    VersionNT = 601 AND MsiNTProductType = 3 Not AppServer
<Condition/>

<Property Id="APPSERVER">
    <RegistrySearch Id="AppServerInstalled"
                    Root="HKLM"
                    Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion"
                    Type="Raw"/>
 </Property>
```

Answer (score 1):

From http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/getting-started/useful-extras:

```
<Condition Message='Windows 95'>Version9X = 400</Condition>
<Condition Message='Windows 95 OSR2.5'>Version9X = 400 AND WindowsBuild = 1111</Condition>
<Condition Message='Windows 98'>Version9X = 410</Condition>
<Condition Message='Windows 98 SE'>Version9X = 410 AND WindowsBuild = 2222</Condition>
<Condition Message='Windows ME'>Version9X = 490</Condition>
<Condition Message='Windows NT4'>VersionNT = 400</Condition>
<Condition Message='Windows NT4 SPn'>VersionNT = 400 AND ServicePackLevel = n</Condition>
<Condition Message='Windows 2000'>VersionNT = 500</Condition>
<Condition Message='Windows 2000 SPn'>VersionNT = 500 AND ServicePackLevel = n</Condition>
<Condition Message='Windows XP'>VersionNT = 501</Condition>
<Condition Message='Windows XP SPn'>VersionNT = 501 AND ServicePackLevel = n</Condition>
<Condition Message='Windows XP Home SPn'>VersionNT = 501 AND MsiNTSuitePersonal AND ServicePackLevel = n</Condition>
<Condition Message='Windows Server 2003'>VersionNT = 502</Condition>
<Condition Message='Windows Vista'>VersionNT = 600</Condition>
<Condition Message='Windows Vista SP1'>VersionNT = 600 AND ServicePackLevel = 1</Condition>
<Condition Message='Windows Server 2008'>VersionNT = 600 AND MsiNTProductType = 3</Condition>
<Condition Message='Windows 7'>VersionNT = 601</Condition>
```

Comment: Hi, I've run the code you provided and now the windows 95 message appears on a windows 2007 system. is there a way of logging out the values of the variables to the log so I can see why it doesn't appear to be taking into account the operating system?

Comment: You say Windows 2007? What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: I'm running the install on Windows 2007 Professional with Service Pack 1 installed. It displays the windows 95 message when I run the above code, should it not display the Windows 7 message?

Comment: sorry windows 7 Professional with Service Pack 1

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't write checks for Worksation vs Server as in the Windows world they are essentially the same thing.  For example, I have a tablet here running Windows 8 with SQL Server 2012 and TFS Server 2012.  Win 8 has everything that is needed, it would have been annoying if the installer had told me  'you aren't running a server o/s'.

If you have a dependency on something that's only in server, write your dependency check for that instead.

Comment: The issue I'm having is that the dependency is only required if the user is running on a windows 2008 R2 system at which point they require the application server to be installed. On other operating systems this isn't required and as such I don't want the message to appear unless it's a windows 2008 r2 system.

Answer (score -1):

After much testing I've managed to get to the answer

To throw a message if you are working on a windows 2008 r2 server you can use the following conditional statement.

```
  <Condition Message="Windows Server 2008R2 installed">
        <NOT (VersionNT = 601 AND MsiNTProductType > 1 )]]>
  </Condition>
```

I have written a custom action to then determine if the application server is installed.

```
<CustomAction()>
Public Shared Function CheckForAppServer(ByVal pobjSession As Session) As ActionResult
    pobjSession.Log("Beginning Check for Application Server")
    Dim lobjRegKey As RegistryKey
    If Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem Then
        pobjSession.Log("64bit Opperating system detected")
        lobjRegKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)
    Else
        pobjSession.Log("32bit Opperating system detected")
        lobjRegKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32)
    End If
    Dim lobjApplicationServerRegKey As Object = lobjRegKey.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppServer", True)
    If lobjApplicationServerRegKey Is Nothing Then
        pobjSession.Log("Application Server registry key not found")
        pobjSession("APPSERVER") = "0"
    Else
        pobjSession.Log(lobjApplicationServerRegKey.ToString)
        pobjSession.Log("Application Server registry key found")
        pobjSession("APPSERVER") = "1"
    End If
    Return ActionResult.Success
End Function
```

Load in my custom action and updating the InstallUISequence and Install Execute Sequence to ensure the property gets set before the conditional message will be thrown.

```
  <InstallUISequence>
        <Custom Action="CA_CheckForAppServer" Before="LaunchConditions" >NOT Installed</Custom>
      </InstallUISequence>
 <InstallExecuteSequence>
 <Custom Action="CA_CheckForAppServer" Before="LaunchConditions" >NOT Installed</Custom>
 </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Updating my conditional message to the following

```
   <Condition Message="Windows Server 2008R2 requires the application server to be enabled">
        <![CDATA[APPSERVER <> 0 OR NOT (VersionNT = 601 AND MsiNTProductType > 1 )]]>
      </Condition>
```